# OpenLDAP: Connection fails on Mac

Tags: openldap

On my Mac, I've installed OpenLDAP, modified /etc/openldap/ldap.conf and specified the path to the cert. However, I keep getting this error:

```
SERVER_DOWN: {
    'info': 
    'error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:
     routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:
        certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)', 
    'desc': "Can't contact LDAP server"
}
```

The ldap.conf has in it:

```
TLS_REQCERT demand
TLS_CACERT /etc/openldap/CA_tncdc01.cer
```

And the cer is there:

```
$ ll /etc/openldap/CA_tncdc01.cer
-rw-r--r--@ 1 eric  staff  1298 Jun 23 09:12 /etc/openldap/CA_tncdc01.cer
```

OpenSSL verify says:

```
$ openssl verify /etc/openldap/CA_tncdc01.cer 
error 18 at 0 depth lookup:self signed certificate
OK
```

And to bind, I use (Python):

```
url = "ldaps://[snip]:636"
l = ldap.initialize(url)
l.simple_bind_s(bind_name, bind_password)
```

All seems to be in order.

Thanks
Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, but the public key of the certificate authority that publish the certificate of your server not seem to be understood. On my client I've got :

BASE    dc=dom, dc=fr
URI     ldaps://srvldap.dom.fr/
TLS_CACERT      /etc/ssl/MyCAcert.pem
TLS_REQCERT     demand

.pem and .cer are the same DER certificate, one is binary, the other is ASCII, can you try the pem format ?

Answer (score 1):

The setting:

```
TLS_REQCERT demand
```

... is the default TLS certificate verification setting.  It is also the MOST STRICT.

The problem you're having is likely because the certificate is self-signed (as you indicated), yet your config says to demand perfect validation results (on part of using 'demand' for TLS_REQCERT).

Using 'demand' will cause any LDAP SSL/TLS connection to fail IF the certificate is not perfect in every respect. This includes issues with a certificate being self-signed, expired, etc etc.

The fact that you've specified your "CA" via TLS_CACERT is good, but the CACERT may be incomplete.  There could be a missing certificate string in the chain somewhere.  Sometimes I've seen it necessary to concatenate multiple CAs together if, for example, a certificate was generated using an Intermediate CA instead of a Root CA.

Regardless, the simplest possible fix is to try replacing 'demand' with 'allow' or 'never', and re-test from there.  If I could choose, I would suggest 'allow' instead of 'never'.

I hope this helps...

Max